# Gerar e ler assets dinamicamente em HTML+Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

Estou fazendo um projeto em Vue.js, onde é gerado um arquivo de audio. Após esse áudio ser gerado, quero poder executá-lo durante a mesma execução.

Aqui é o componente que gara o player de audio (está condicionalmente ligada por essa variável "audio", que só é verdadeira depois que o audio já foi criado):

```html
<div ref="base" id="base">
    <solution-base
    @generate-audio="generateAudio">
  </solution-base>
  <audio-base v-if="audio" class="audio" :key="enteredText"></audio-base> 
</div>
```

E aqui é onde é feita a chamada para a API que produz o audio:

```js
   async generateAudio(enteredText,selected){
      this.audio = true;
      await api.post('/createAudio', null, { params: {
        text:enteredText,
        tool: selected
      }})
    }
```

Porém quando a página é acessada aparece esse erro:

> Error: Can't resolve '../audio.wav' in
> '/Users/pilarfernandez/ProjetosPUC/text-to-speech-tester/project/src/components'

Entendo que esse erro seja por que, de fato, o arquivo não existe na pasta. Porém, o arquivo seria gerado durante a execução e com o erro não é possível já que a página não carrega.

Como posso fazer o HTML não dar esse erro caso o arquivo não exista, e poder criá-lo durante a execução?

Comment: Olá! Hm, não sei se entendi bem seu código, se puder colocar o código do componente onde o audio é lido, já que o erro está acontecendo lá

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Você está querendo criar um arquivo na máquina do usuário? Se for isso mesmo, lembre-se que uma aplicação Vue é executada no cliente (navegador) e por questões óbvias de segurança não tem permissão para criar arquivos no filesystem. Se o problema for esse, o que você pode fazer é... criar um [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob) com o conteúdo do arquivo e disparar um evento para fazer o download do mesmo.

Comment: Sim, estou criando o arquivo na máquina do usuário. 
Isso está sendo feito no backend (node.js), por isso no Vue seria só ler mesmo.